# Provide link to iframe via js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe with src but I want to provide the link to src via javascript on click of the button. How do I pass the value?

EDIT: The webpage refreshes everytime I click on the button. It displays the webpage and then refreshes it to display again. How to avoid this?

```
    <button type="button" onclick = "Open()">Click Me!</button>

    <iframe id="iframe"
  src="" //Provide link here
  style="
    z-index: 10;
    display: None;
  ">
</iframe>

<script>
    function Open() {
      let myIframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
        myIframe.style.display = 'block';
        iframe.src = "www.mylink.com"
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: `myIframe.src`?

Comment: @BenM But the website gets refreshed everytime i click on the button. That is, when I click on the button the second time, it displays the website and then it refreshes for one second to display it again. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not referencing `myIframe` when setting src in the example, you need to do `myIframe.src = 'https://www.mylink.com'`

Comment: Ah yes but the problem is it refreshes every time i click the button. That is it shows the website and then it refreshes for a sec to reload it again. Can this be avoided?

Comment: that's because you're overriding the current src, if it's going to be static, I'd just set the src on the elements attribute and toggle the visibility.

Comment: Yeah that is what I had done. But is there any other way? Because there will be multiple buttons with different src links and I would like to use only one iframe.

Comment: I do not believe so, unless you added a check to see if the src matches the current one (ex. `if myIframe.src === newSrc`)

Comment: I am doing it like this ```if(myIframe.src === "www.mywebpage.com")
        {
            
        } else
        {
            console.log(myIframe.src);
            myIframe.src = "www.mywebpage.com";
        }```
But it still gets called. The console still gets called. I feel the src gets empty because I close it using ``` myIframe.style.display = 'None';```

Comment: wow very bizarre haha, this is about the limit of my knowledge on weird edge cases with iframes tho

Comment: oh just make sure that you're comparing with `http` or `https` in the string too

Comment: Yes I check with both. The link is exactly the same.

Comment: It is very annoying to see that iframe opens the page and then reloads it.

Comment: ahh i found it, the issue is no trailing slash on root, see this codepen https://codepen.io/dhazelett/pen/rNjYYed

Comment: Yes that is the issue. Thanks alot :) but if you do find the reason for it to reload then please post it here. For now I shall use this alternative solution :)